# Node JS: get number of files in a directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesystems

To get the number of files stored in a specific directory on the filesystem with Node JS, is there anything more efficient than [fs.readdir](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_callback)?

`fs.readdir` returns an array with all the filenames, and the length of the array represents the total number of files.

In case one doesn't need to know the file names though, and only wants the total number of files, is there any Node JS method that would be more efficient / performant?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There is not another option that is built into node.js.

If you want to know how many file are in a directory, you have to read the directory to get the list of files and then count those.  Note: you may find both files and directory entries in a directory so if you literally want just files, you have to skip over and not count the directory entries.